# remote debugging stops when reaching the breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I am debugging a c# plugin remotely. the solution is in VS 2017

I have set up remote debugging regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019

debugging starts fine, when I start debugging on VS, the application starts on the target machine, but exactly when it reaches a breakpoint, the app on target machine closes and thus an error comes up on dev-machine " connection to ... lost, debugging will be aborted"

I have tried anything that I was suspicious too, I tried a clean build,  also tried to delete all breakpoints and set some again.

when I delete all breakpoints no crash occurs. I have checked modules, the symbol file related to the dll I am trying to debug is loaded.

I really have no clue what is happening when I add breakpoints

Comment: Where do you store debugging symbols? They are loaded when execution stops on a breakpoint. Maybe that could make connection lost. Are they on your machine or on remote?

Comment: i actually tried both ways, having them on both dev machine and the remote machine, and having them only on the dev machine.